# SQL SERVER 2016 -CAN execute SP with parameters inside a Function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have an SP which brings a table with some fields and subtracts the results to another table, I tried to do this as a function but as you know you can not use DML sentences in a function so I created this SP:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE SP_Integraciones_AsignarLotesLineas
    @Cantidad numeric, @producto nvarchar(max), @bodega nvarchar(max)

AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN

    DECLARE @temp as table(idLoteT nvarchar(max), CantidadT numeric, FechaT date) 
    DECLARE @loteAc nvarchar(Max), @CantidadAc numeric, @restante numeric , @Cont numeric, @fechaAc date, @resultado nvarchar(max)

    SET @Cont = @Cantidad
    DECLARE CursoIns CURSOR SCROLL 
    FOR SELECT IdLote, CONVERT(NUMERIC,cantidad), Fecha
                        FROM   tblintegraciones_lotes
                        WHERE idproducto = @producto 
                        AND Bodega = @bodega
                        AND cantidad > '0.0'
                        ORDER  BY fecha ASC

    OPEN CursoIns
    FETCH CursoIns INTO  @loteAc, @CantidadAc, @fechaAc

    WHILE( @Cont > 0  AND @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  )
      BEGIN

          IF( @CantidadAc >= @Cont )
              BEGIN
              SET @restante = @CantidadAc- @Cont 
                  INSERT INTO @temp(
                  idLoteT, CantidadT, FechaT
                  )VALUES(
                   @loteAc, @Cont, @fechaAc
                  )
                  UPDATE tblintegraciones_lotes SET Cantidad = @restante WHERE idProducto = @producto AND IdLote = @loteAc
                  SET @Cont = @cont - @CantidadAc                 
              END
              
            ELSE
              BEGIN
              SET @Cont = @Cont - @CantidadAc
              SET @restante =  @Cont - @CantidadAc    
                     INSERT INTO @temp(
                    idLoteT, CantidadT, FechaT
                    )VALUES(
                     @loteAc, @CantidadAc, @fechaAc
                    )
                    UPDATE tblintegraciones_lotes SET Cantidad = 0 WHERE idProducto = @producto AND IdLote = @loteAc                
              END
              FETCH CursoIns INTO  @loteAc, @CantidadAc, @fechaAc
        END 

    CLOSE CursoIns;  
    DEALLOCATE CursoIns; 

    SELECT * FROM @temp

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK
    DECLARE @DescripcionError AS nvarchar(max)
    SET @DescripcionError = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    RAISERROR (@DescripcionError, 18, 1, 'Inventario - lotes - Integraciones', 5)
  END CATCH
END
GO
```

but the problem is that I must run this in a select since I need that query parcing to JSON, so there should be 2 solutions:

1. Execute this SP in a select sentence
2. Create some function that calls the SP.

Can you help me how can I execute this SP in a function or find the best soluction?

Here the Query that I need execute this:

```
(SELECT CASE
                     WHEN MFAC.codigo IN ('ME-14009',
                                          'ME-14010',
                                          'ME-14011') THEN 'IMP-BOLSAP'
                     ELSE MFAC.codigo
                 END AS ItemCode,
                 REPLACE(MFAC.cantidad, ',', '.') AS Quantity,
                 CASE WHEN MFAC.codigo LIKE '%PV%' THEN MFAC.valor ELSE null END as Price,
                 REPLACE(MFAC.descuento, ',', '.') AS DiscountPercent,
                 CASE
                     WHEN MFAC.codbodega = 'PV-PER' THEN 'PV-DQU'
                     ELSE MFAC.codbodega
                 END AS WarehouseCode,
                 @OcrCode3 AS CostingCode3,
                 @OcrCode3 AS COGSCostingCode3
                    FOR JSON PATH
                  ) DocumentLines
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that. You're not allowed side effects from a function. Full stop. It doesn't matter how you try to wrap that up in extra layers, it's still not going to happen.

Comment: It seems like you are implementing a queue as a table and want a single query to "grab" an element from the table, mark it as such, and return the relevant information in a single SELECT statement. If so, I think you need to adjust your expectations.

Comment: `@Cantidad numeric` This is a bad habit. Do you know what the default precision and scale are when you do not specify them? Are those defaults appropriate? This `cantidad > '0.0'` suggests the defaults are not.

Comment: Aside... _Caution: Avoid the use of the sp\_ prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure with the same name._ Ref: [CREATE PROCEDURE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql)

Comment: For a start, it looks like you could remove the cursor, and instead use a combination of window functions and `OUTPUT INTO @temp`. Then at the end you can put `SELECT ... FROM @temp` into a `FOR JSON PATH` query. Without proper sample data and expected results it's hard to say more.